# On a variant of Nim game

Tags: game-theory

2 students play the Nim game as follows: There is only 1 heap of stones,  they can take from the heap $2^x$ ($x$ can be 0) number of stones each time. The student who has taken the last stone wins. For which number of stones does the first play win? How should he play? Prove that strategy works.

My approach: I have made a guess that the first player is the winner if number of stones is not a multiply of 3. So for the case when the number of stones is 3, the second player just takes all the remaining stones. I wonder if induction would be a valid approach ?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The usual starting point would be to solve the problem for various small sizes and to look for themes and patterns.

Comment: Is there just one heap at the beginning of the game? In any event, you should probably start with the one-heap case.

Comment: Do you know about N and P positions?  You are asking to separate those two.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you be more specific? I am new to this topic.

Comment: Post edit:  Yes, induction is a good idea.

Comment: You can read in Wikipedia about Nim and the Sprague-Grundy theorem

Comment: @lulu So firstly, I proved that for $N = 3k$, then player 1 loses. For $N = 3(k+1)$, it is easy to see player 1 loses. I believe I should check the case $N = 3k + 1$ and $N = 3k + 2$ as well to prove the strategy. Will it be the correct way to prove the strategy ?

Comment: Absolutely.  Note that you are really done already:  if $N=3k+1$ then player $1$ can remove $2^0$ stones to hand player $2$ a multiple of $3$, which you have already shown to be a losing position.  Similarly if $N=3k+2$.

Comment: I suggest:  when you are done, post your solution below.  That way people here can check your work and the site can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove that first player will win if number of stones is not a multiply of 3.

First, for $N = 3$, player 1 will lose since player 2 will take all the remain stones.
If $N = 3k$, for $k = 1$ we proved that player 1 will lose. Suppose it is true for $k \ge 1$, we need to prove it holds for $k + 1$.

$N = 3(k+1) = 3N + 3 $.

Clearly, player 1 will lose.

If $N = 3k + 1$, for $3k$ player 2 will win then for then for $3k + 1$, player 1 will win by taking the final stone.

Similarly if $N = 3k + 2$, player 1 will take 2 remaining stones.

Therefore the first player will win if the number of stones is not multiply of 3.